# Asp.Net MVC Dynamic Model Binding Prefix

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Is there any way of changing the binding prefix with a value which comes from the request parameters?

I have many nested search popups, and all of them shares the same ViewModel.

I can add a binding prefix to all the fields when requesting for the Search filters, but i don't know how can i make the [Bind(Prefix = "")] to work with values coming from the request parameters.

```
// get the search filters with the bindingPrefix we need
public ActionResult Search(string bindingPrefix)
{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = bindingPrefix;
    SearchViewModel model = new SearchViewModel
    {
        BindingPrefix = bindingPrefix
    };

    return PartialView("_SearchFilters", model); 
}

// post the search filters values
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search([Bind(Prefix = model.BindingPrefix)]SearchViewModel model)
{

}
```

Comment: Why do you change the binding prefix in your Action?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why you would want to do this, but this should work.

In your form on the view, have a hidden value

```
@Html.Hidden("BindingPrefix", Model.BindingPrefix)
```

Modify your action to the following

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel model)
{
    UpdateModel(model, model.BindingPrefix);
}
```